# Python: How to parse a Tiktok url from a given text

Tags: python, parsing, url, python-re

Hello I am trying to parse a text and extract the Tiktok Url that it is in it

```
text = "This is a text https://www.tiktok.com/@tt_user/video/7620173214578963251 and more text"
```

Normally in python, to parse an url, I use the following regex:

```
import re
url = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", text).group("url")
```

But this method fails for tiktok (i assume it is for the "@" in the url)

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I would like to know how to extract my tiktok urls properly by (1) using a regex or (2) Using another method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
url = re.search("(?P<url>https?:\/\/[^\s]+)", text).group("url")
```

You need to escape '\' the '/'

Comment: It worked. Can you explain me a little more why did it work?

Comment: @TheDan because you have to escape slash with backslash  because slash is special character